# programmatically change language of flutter i18n apps doesn't work in iOS

Tags: ios, internationalization, flutter

I used flutter_i18n plugin (Android Studio) to generate i18n.dart(`class S`) and `S.of(context).locale_msg` will return the locale string. The main code is shown below.
Language should be changed programmatically by invoking `onLocaleChange(locale)` when click the button in HomePage. It works well in Android simulator, **but won't change language in iOS simulator**. Wonder what's wrong with my code?

```
class _PaperMoonAppState extends State<PaperMoonApp> {
  SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate _localeOverrideDelegate;

  void onLocaleChange(Locale locale) {
    setState(() {
      if (appVars.appConfig.changeLanguage(locale)) {
        _localeOverrideDelegate = new SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate(locale);
        appVars.saveConfig(); //print save config file...
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate.onLocaleChange = this.onLocaleChange;
    appVars.loadConfig().then((AppConfig _config) {
      appVars.appConfig = _config;

      setState(() {
        _localeOverrideDelegate =
            new SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate(appVars.appConfig.getLocale());
      });
    });
    _localeOverrideDelegate =
        new SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate(Locale('zh', ''));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(_localeOverrideDelegate.overriddenLocale);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Paper Moon",
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        _localeOverrideDelegate,
        S.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: const <Locale>[
        Locale("ja", ""),
        Locale("en", ""),
        Locale("zh", ""),
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback:
          S.delegate.resolution(fallback: _localeOverrideDelegate.overriddenLocale),
      home: HomePage(),
//      routes: _buildRoutes(),
    );
  }
}
```

Custom LocalizationDelegate:

```
class SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<WidgetsLocalizations> {
  //class static vars:
  //onLocaleChange should be bind to MaterialApp function containing setState().
  static LocaleChangeCallback onLocaleChange;

  // for instance
  final Locale overriddenLocale;

  const SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate(this.overriddenLocale);

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => overriddenLocale != null;



  @override
  Future<WidgetsLocalizations> load(Locale locale) =>
      S.delegate.load(overriddenLocale);

  @override
  bool shouldReload(SpecifiedLocalizationDelegate old) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on your code, the only thing that seems to be missing is this:

open `ios/Runner/Info.plist` and add:

```
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>ja</string>
        <string>en</string>
        <string>zh</string>
    </array>
```

As far I as know, by now (march/2019), flutter doesn't yet add automatically the list of supported languages to this file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [i18n_extensions](https://pub.dev/packages/i18n_extension), but with the same issue...

What worked for me, was use this:

```
supportedLocales: const <Locale>[
    const Locale('en'),
    const Locale('pt'),
],
```

Instead of this:

```
  supportedLocales: const <Locale>[
    const Locale('en', 'US'),
    const Locale('pt', 'BR'),
  ],
```

And then, my i18n.dart. file i've change from this:

```
extension Localization on String {
  static final _t = Translations.from("en_us", {
    passwordInput: {
      "en_us": "Password",
      "pt_br": "Senha",
    },
    searchingTitle: {
      "en_us": "Scanning for devices...",
      "pt_br": "Procurando dispositivos...",
    },
    ...
```

To this:

```
extension Localization on String {
  static final _t = Translations.from("en", {
    passwordInput: {
      "en": "Password",
      "pt": "Senha",
    },
    searchingTitle: {
      "en": "Scanning for devices...",
      "pt": "Procurando dispositivos...",
    },
```

It works fine for me.