# Locale from web app is always 'en' Flutter

Tags: flutter, locale, flutter-web

I have my app that is correctly getting device locale from Android and iOS, but not from web. I get the web locale language code as `ui.window.locale.languageCode` using `ui.dart` package. In my Mac I set the system language to Italian, time zone is set to Italy and Location services set to enabled but when I run my app on Chrome it always return 'en_'.
Is there something I am missing to do?
This is the code in main() :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    return MaterialApp(
        title: '',
        color: Colors.red,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          const AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', 'US'),
          const Locale('it', 'IT')
//        const Locale('es', 'ES'),
        ],
        localeResolutionCallback:
            (Locale locale, Iterable<Locale> supportedLocales) {
          for (Locale supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
            if (kIsWeb) {
              Locale webLocale = Locale(ui.window.locale.languageCode, '');
              print('system locale is ${webLocale}');
              return webLocale;
            } else if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode ||
                supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
              print('device Locale is $locale');
              return supportedLocale;
            }
          }
          return supportedLocales.first;
        },
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday with iOS and web. I resolved the iOS problem with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53674805/programmatically-change-language-of-flutter-i18n-apps-doesnt-work-in-ios). I suppose that the issue for web applications will be fixed in the future (web is not considered as a stable Flutter feature).

If you really need to create an internationalized app on iOS, Android and web, you can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_device_locale).

```
FutureBuilder<Locale>(
  future: DeviceLocale.getCurrentLocale(),
  builder: (context, localeData) {
    if(!localeData.hasData) return Container( color: Colors.white);
    Locale locale = localeData.data;
    return MaterialApp(
      // localizationsDelegates, supportedLocales, ...

      // « _ » is the locale detected by flutter
      // You should use the locale detected by the library instead
      localeResolutionCallback: (_, supportedLocales) {
        for (var supportedLocaleLanguage in supportedLocales) {
          if (supportedLocaleLanguage.languageCode == locale.languageCode) return supportedLocaleLanguage;
        }

        // If device not support with locale to get language code then default get first on from the list
        return supportedLocales.first;
      }
    );
  },
);
```

You can call "Localizations.localeOf(context)" to get the locale in a child of the MaterialApp widget.

It seems that this package is currently not compatible with desktop applications.

I didn't check on the "issues" tab of the Flutter Github page if the issue was signaled. Maybe I should signal it this evening.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answering. Indeed the issue is only with web. AFAIK a fix has been merged and we should have it available with the next version of flutter. I tested the actual stable master and beta branches but still got the error so it hasn't been rolled out yet. As I'm not in a hurry to internationalize the web version I'll try and wait to see if next rolled out version will in effect have the issue fixed before implementing the suggested plug in as I should rewrite quite a lot. Thank you very much for suggesting the plugin dough. ;)
Cheers.

Comment: I hope you are right about the fix. The package that I mentioned is not very popular (6 stars on Github), so I don't think that it can be considered as reliable. But I don't have a better alternative for now.

Comment: You can follow it here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54669 It'll soon be fixed I hope. Cheers

Comment: It's finally fixed.
Update to the last master channel and Locale now works perfectly on web as well.

Answer (score 4):

Finally locale on master branch work as expected.
Updating to Channel master, 1.19.0-4.0.pre.73 solved the problem.